# Upload Photo in ASP

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I have a form where user need to enter their particular details. Besides that user also need to upload their photo using the same form. I have tried to used examples from the internet on how to do the upload photo part. But I still can't get the codes run. Do I have to install any component first? Really need your advice. Thank you.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

If your host has it installed (and most ASP hosts do) you can use ASPUpload (http://www.aspupload.com/) to achieve just what you describe.